# Having issues running java project through command line

Tags: maven

I am completely new to using maven. I have created a maven project and exported it to eclipse. Maven automatically created the `src/test/java` and `src/main/java`. 
I created a java script and successfully ran it in eclipse. But when I try running it through command line, I got an error that says:

> cannot find or load main class.

When I checked my project directory, there were two classfile paths: `classes` and `test-classes`. The script I was running is the one in 'test-classes' but it is not the main class. But the path to the main class executes successfully but that is not where my script is located.

The command I was using for the main classfile is: 
`java -cp target/Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.App`.

The command for the test classfile is : 
`java -cp target/Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.AppTest`. 
This second command gives me the error I mentioned.

Please how do I get around this issue?

Comment: Make sure to export a runnable jar from the Maven project in eclipse -- not just a jar.  I think you mean that you imported the project into eclipse, not exported it.  It would be best to create a new Maven project in eclipse and copy the code files into it to ensure it is really configured for use in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, everything in `src/test/java` is supposed to be for testing only. That is, you should place only your test classes in this directory. Maven will run them before building the final JAR, but it will NOT include them in it.

If you absolutely need a JAR with your test classes, have a look at [How to create a jar containing test classes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html).